# wordpress error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class stuser

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm busy building a wordpress website, and this error pops up occasionally, and from there onward I cannot access the wordpress site.

The error is

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class stuser in
>   /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/74/3540574/html/wp-content/themes/traveler/inc/admin/class.user.php
>   on line 16

The peculiar thing is, if i wait about 10 minutes and refresh the page I can then login and continue as normal. But after working for a while the error re-appears.

I have little coding experience and am not sure how to fix this. I am a noob with code. Perhaps some kind developer could help me fix this error?

I would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Tony

[image]

Comment: Are there any Wordpress Experts who could assist with this frustrating error that appears?

Answer (score 0):

`class stuser` is hooked into something and gets instantiated.  I can only guess it's on the admin side if you're able to login (& possibly see the site without being logged in).

I don't have the rep to comment, so without asking questions, go to that file and comment out `new stuster()` -- see if this file/class is necessary to your theme development.  I've been doing this for sometime and I wouldn't say it is necessary.

Comment: Hi Kat firstly thanks you so much for responding and your willingness to help. I am not that knowledgeable on wordpress coding, could you maybe explain in more simple terms on how I could fix this or where i could navigate to to fix it. I can login to wordpress via ftp if that helps you.

Comment: Hi Kat. I've added an image screenshot i took under the initial question I asked. This is what I'm seeing when I logged in via FTP. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: Tony, try changing STUser to STUser111 or something -- changing the name should help us get closer.  The error essentially says this is being declared twice...without seeing your repo, I couldn't tell you where the duplicate is...did you happen to copy a folder planning to override certain files?